# displaySurface constraint not restricting user share screen selection options

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, get-display-media

Adding displaySurface does not provoke option restriction for the user before sharing his own screen.
I am trying to limit those options to only let the user select anything except browser tabs.[image: ss]

I tried setting displaySurface explicitly to 'monitor' and still all options being showed up.

```
async startCaptureMD() {
  let captureStream = null;
  var screen_constraints = {
     video: {
        cursor: "always",
        displaySurface: "monitor"
     }
  };
  try{
     captureStream = await 
     navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(screen_constraints);
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
  }
  return captureStream;
},
```

The expected result is to show 'Your Entire Screen' or 'Application Window' and not 'Chrome Tab'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture#Options_and_constraints) docs explain that it is for security:

> Constraints never cause changes to the list of sources available for capture by the Screen Sharing API. This ensures that web applications can't force the user to share specific content by restricting the source list until only one item is left.

The [spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/#dom-mediadevices-getdisplaymedia) says:

> The user agent MUST let the end-user choose which display surface to share out of all available choices every time, and MUST NOT use constraints to limit that choice.

So the browser is doing the right thing. It seems `displaySurface` is an **output** value only. If you already have a `MediaStreamTrack` to call `getSettings()` on, then you can read displaySurface.

I also was confused, so I fixed the MDN docs. <s>The MDN docs need updating to not list `displaySurface` as "A string (or array of strings) indicating what type or types of screen surface to allow the user to select".</s>

Comment: Very weird, why would someone would use/read such output value ? otherwise we want to restrict some screens before end-user tries to select since for example when you try to open a terminal/cmd instance with multiple tabs and you choose a single tab for your share screen viewer and you try to switch between tabs the screen goes black. So i would preferably choose to eliminate such behavior by restricting some choices instead. Anyway thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: How does Google Meet do this then? (meet.google.com)

Comment: @YousefAmar Google Chrome is shipped with a hidden extension named "Google Hangouts" which only works on Google domains. Google Meet uses that extension. The extension itself uses this to achieve that:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture#method-chooseDesktopMedia

Comment: @AlicanC Thanks, I found that out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63658198/1477456). Isn't this incredibly anti-competitive though? How is Google getting away with it? Doesn't seem like anyone's saying anything about it

Comment: @YousefAmar it is. I actually brought this up, but didn't get an answer:
https://twitter.com/AlicanC/status/1314280197546545154

Comment: Is there a way to change what is shown at default then? Still allowing the user to have choice?

Comment: Would like to know too