# How does Google Meet allow you to screen share from another tab?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, get-display-media

In [Google Meet](https://meet.google.com), if you click "Present Now" then "A Chrome Tab", it brings up a window that lets you share from another tab. This is different to the standard [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API) as if you simply run

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
})
```

you get a window where you can choose between sharing your whole screen, sharing a window, or sharing a tab. I would like to limit this to tab only. I have tried applying constraints like:

```
video: { displaySurface: 'browser' }
```

or

```
video: { displaySurface: { exact: 'browser' } }
```

however, [the specs say that this doesn't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/displaySurface) and indeed it doesn't. But if that's the case, then how does Google Meet do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google Meet uses the older extension API for screensharing. [This API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) allows restricting the source types. It is still available but requires an extension (Google meet delivers a preinstalled extensions).

The standard getDisplayMedia does not allow restricting the types of displaySurface.

Update 2022: as on Chrome 107 some of these options are available via getDisplayMedia too, see [this blog post](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/screen-sharing-controls/) for details

Comment: Could you elaborate on this preinstalled extension please? Is it baked into Chromium or something?

Comment: it is -- [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/resources/hangout_services/thunk.js?q=thunk.js)

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems like it's only for *.google.com domains too. Isn't this super anti-competitive? How is Google getting away with this?