# Get CPU, Network & Memory stats in web browser

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Google Meet uses a preinstalled extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/63658375/4479807 [extension_code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/resources/hangout_services/thunk.js?q=thunk.js) to gain access to CPU, Memory and Network resources used by the Tab/browser, is there anyway in WebRTC to do the same? [GetStats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getStats) does provide some metrics like QualityLimitationReason, but nothing like browserCpuUsage mentioned in the extension.