# How is Google Meet able to show CPU usage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I noticed this today in my Chrome.

[image: Google Meet CPU Usage chart]

Google Meet is showing a chart of CPU usage in their "Troubleshooting" panel. I'm wondering if there's an existing API for this or is it a clever trick I'm not aware of.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63658198/how-does-google-meet-allow-you-to-screen-share-from-another-tab

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was curious about this as well when I saw the CPU Usage graph on the Troubleshooting page on the Google Meet's page. So googled a lot and I couldn't find any proper answer as to how it is being achieved apart from this link: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/system_cpu#method-getInfo.

So, I went through the minified source code of the Google Meet's site and it turns out Google Meet is using this but not on their webpage directly, because it is for chrome extensions only, but through the `Google Hangouts Extension` which is present in Chrome, Brave and the new Microsoft Edge (Chromium-based).

[image]

The chrome extension is calling the `chrome.system.cpu` API to get the information about the processor, core count, temperatures, etc., and these details are being passed to the Google Meets page via `window.postMessage` API and [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/) between Chrome Extension and a Webpage.

This is a neat little way to achieve this if you are the creator of the browser :P.

Comment: Example: https://books.google.de/books?id=KtYNEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=chrome+api+gpuCpuUsage+browserCpuUsage&source=bl&ots=VVx7ruhQdA&sig=ACfU3U056XyPVaJ7uAFuNkHrBlQ4lnraVw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwvPXKqMHuAhUR2KQKHf4WBTMQ6AEwCnoECBUQAg#v=onepage&q=chrome%20api%20gpuCpuUsage%20browserCpuUsage&f=false

as pdf https://www.cse.chalmers.se/~andrei/cans20.pdf

Comment: Hi @Vibhor where did you figure out the GOogle Hangouts extension is installed by default in Chrome. I mean your screenshot, how can I check that?

Comment: Open this page `chrome://inspect/#extensions`, you'll find `Google Hangouts` as pre-installed extensions.

Comment: On a tangent, the [CPU Pressure API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/compute-pressure/) is one proposal how to expose such data directly to the browser.

Comment: Interesting find @DenverCoder9. Google is finally working on making this API publically accessible to the devs. Currently, it is in its initial draft stage but let's hope it gets approved and implemented in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, they are using Chrome specific API since this will not work on other browsers.
The closest thing that I've found is https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/system_cpu#method-getInfo

Below is a screenshot from Firefox stating that this will work only on Chrome.

[image: Snapshot from Firefox]

Comment: It wouldn't be the API you're mentioning - that is only available from extensions. Mystery continues...