# Get CPU Usage detail in browser

Tags: javascript, web, browser, cpu-usage, webassembly

I saw this CPU Usage real-time chart in the Google Meet's Troubleshooting section and I was wondering how to get the CPU Usage details in the browser so that I can plot a real-time chart on my webpage.

I googled about it a lot but couldn't find any proper solution about the topic that can directly work on the browser without, apart from the logical core count that `navigator.hardwareConcurrency` returns.

Maybe using WebAssembly this can be achieved?

[image]

P.S.: This is for research purposes and for use in my personal projects.

Comment: This proposal's explainer [talks about](https://github.com/WICG/js-self-profiling#facebooks-profiler-polyfill) something facebook would have done using a Worker and SharedArrayBuffers, but I'm not able to find a source for this "profiler" in a fast research. Maybe you'll get more luck than myself. (and on localhost you can also try the API directly on chrome, though I don't know how easy to infer CPU usage from this).

Comment: @Kaiido I think this Facebook Profiler is more or less similar to the profiler that is there in Chrome but Facebook is trying to make it accessible as a JS API so that more users can use it plus they have been using it in some of their sites. But this is not what I am looking for plus I think this is not how the CPU Usage graph above is implemented. I did some research in the past 2 days and I actually found out how Google is getting the CPU Usage and I'll be posting that as an answer sometime today.

Comment: Not at all no. The Facebook profiler they talk about was 100% JS, it used SharedArrayBuffers and a Worker. That wasn't a built-in profiler at all (FB doesn't do browsers).

Comment: Added link to the answer that was posted by me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65378446/4410366